Does "I rushed to do homework" mean I quickly went to my homework and did it at any rate (maybe be fast or slow) or I did the homework quickly?
The dictionary says

rush to do something: to do something very quickly and without delay
I rushed to pack my suitcase before she came back.
He rushed to help his comrade.

Does "I rushed to do homework" mean I quickly went to my homework and did it at any rate (maybe be fast or slow) or I did the homework quickly?
Say it was a 2-page homework and it took me 30 minutes if I did it fast and it took me 2 hours if I did it slow.
Does "I rushed to do homework" mean I just quickly went to my homework and we don't know if I did it fast or slow?

You have the dictionary answer so I'm voting to close this.

@Lambie, look at a native English speaker (Colin Fine) say "It could be ambiguous, but I would probably interpret it as your first". The dictionary is ambiguous or sometimes even wrong.

The dictionary is right. I rushed to do my homework so we could leave on time for the movies.

I don't think it's something very likely to be said.
It could be ambiguous, but I would probably interpret it as your first, because for your second I would expect something like I rushed through my homework or I rushed to get my homework finished.
For your first, I would expect I rushed to get started on my homework.
